# What to do after using UserSettingsFragment to login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

So I am able to successfully login and logout using the UserSettingsFragment, but I cannot seem to get any additional functionality to work after logging in. I would like to replace the UserSettingsFragment with a fragment of my own after successful login and my current code that doesn't work is this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    userSettingsFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);        
    FacebookHelperFragment fbhf = new FacebookHelperFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fb_helper_frag, fbhf)
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

When I run it, it looks like the fbhf flashes on the screen momentarily, but then it immediately goes back to displaying the default login screen from the UserSettingsFragment which shows the logged in user's name and picture with a logout button. Also, I really don't want to use any deprecated code. Is anyone really using the UserSettingsFragment, I haven't seen much usage of it other than to logout only, or as part of the SessionLoginSample.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer came to me in my sleep.

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    userSettingsFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == -1) {
        FacebookHelperFragment fbhf = new FacebookHelperFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().hide(userSettingsFragment)
                .add(R.id.fb_helper_frag, fbhf).addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Just needed to hide the static userSettingsFragment before dynamically adding my FacebookHelperFragment.